# Determine collinear lines using SQL geography data type?

Tags: c#, mapping, gis

I'm using some SQL geography column to store some lines in a database. I then convert the lines into long\lat lines and drawn on a map.  I need to adjust the lines to be thicker if they occupy the same space.  I'm curious if anyone knows of a way to detect if the lines are collinear using the SQL Geography type or any other method.  Thanks

Comment: This question might be better answered at http://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a mapping expert, but shouldn't you just be able to check the start and endpoints of the line segment? If you get two line segments with the same start and endpoints then you have co-linearity, and you can implement whatever funky logic you want after that.

Comment: I think OP needs more than just same start/end - any overlapping needs to be thicker, I'd imagine.

Comment: If there was overlap, he wouldn't need to implement any logic to make the lines thicker. Only if they are exactly co-linear.

Comment: @JonMartin That would seem to be the obvious answer, but I'm not a mapping expert either and have no real experience with this type of problem. I was just curious if anyone else had experience with something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a thin buffer around the lines, and then take the intersection of the buffers.